# Backpropagation to calculate derivative

Tags: calculus, neural-networks

I have got a task to calculate $\frac{dv}{dx}$ using backpropagation, where

$v = z^2 + y$
$z = \frac{y}{3}$
$y = \arctan(x)$

Am I supposed to just use chain rule here or do something else? I'd really like to see an example of calculating this.
I did something like this

$\frac{dv}{dz}$ = $2z$
$\frac{dz}{dy}$ = $\frac{1}{3}$
$\frac{∂v}{∂y}$ = $1$
$\frac{dv}{dy}$ = $\frac{∂v}{∂z}$$*$$\frac{dz}{dy}$ + $\frac{∂v}{∂y}$ = $\frac{2}{3}z$ $+1$
$\frac{dv}{dx}$ = $\frac{dv}{dy}$$*$$\frac{dy}{dx}$ = $(\frac{2}{3}z+1)*$ $\frac{1}{(1+x^2)}$

Comment: Also, please do not post questions that read like a text message:  "i,"  "sth".

Comment: Yes, you are supposed to use the chain rule.

Comment: Yes use the chain rule. If you like you can write this as $v=z^2+y=(y/3)^2+y=(arctan/3)^2+arctan(x)$ and calculate the derivative.

Comment: My teacher wrote that i'm not supposed to use "normal" differentiation but the backpropagation. So am I supposed to simply calculate it like that?